# How do I retrieve the name property of a radio button in c#

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I've created a series of radio button controls in C#. `(radCompany, radProperty etc.)`
I've set their group name to be the same (282_Type) so they function as a list of radio buttons.

How do I retrieve the name `(like: ct100$m$dfgadjkfasdghasdkjfg$282_Type)` in c# so I can use this in a Javascript method i'm creating?

The values output are:

```
Radion Button 1  
id="ct223423432243_radCompany" name="ct100$sdfsdf$sdfsdf$282_Type"  
Radion Button 2  
id="ct223423432243_radProperty" name="ct100$sdfsdf$sdfsdf$282_Type"
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to reference the [ClientID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid.aspx) of the control; this is the id in the final html.

Of course, another approach might be to use some other attribute (such as the css etc), and use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) to find it; jQuery takes a lot of DOM pain away from javascript. It is interesting that jQuery is now even supported by VS2008 (with intellisense etc).

I'm currently reading [jQuery in Action](http://www.manning.com/bibeault/), and liking it much. To take an example straight from the book (on the subject of radios):

```
var x = $('[name=radioGroup]:checked').val();
```

which returns the value of the single checked radio button in the group, or `undefined` if none is selected.

Re getting the name; it uses the internal `UniqueGroupName` property, which does a lot of mangling. An option (but not an attractive one) would be to use reflection to read `UniqueGroupName`. Alternatively, use something simple like a literal control. Gawd I hate the ASP.NET forms model... roll on MVC...

Fianlly - I'm currently looking at the public [VS2010 CTP](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=922b4655-93d0-4476-bda4-94cf5f8d4814&displaylang=en&tm) image; one of the new additions for ASP.NET is static `ClientID`s, by setting ClientIdMode = Static on the control. A bit overdue, but not unwelcome.

Comment: (Deleted my suggestion of using ID so as not to distract from the correct answer.)

Comment: This does return the control id, however this is not the name of the list of radiobuttons so it returns the ID attribute rather then the name attribute which is what I want.

Comment: Could you clarify what the name and id are coming down as? I'm not entirely sure what you are seeing...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion however, I'm almost certainly not going to use jQuery for this, as this would add complexity unnessarily. An option is to not use c# created radiobuttons, just straight HTML ones.

Comment: Given the ID, you can easily find the control in JavaScript and then get the name, surely.

Comment: @Jon - that would be easier and more supportable than reflection ;-p

Comment: I've just found that VS2010 makes things slightly easier (updated)

Comment: Thanks for your help guys. +1 to Jon. (I'm using your approach)

Answer (score 1):

http://reflector.webtropy.com/default.aspx/Net/Net/3@5@50727@3053/DEVDIV/depot/DevDiv/releases/whidbey/netfxsp/ndp/fx/src/xsp/System/Web/UI/WebControls/RadioButton@cs/2/RadioButton@cs

```
internal string UniqueGroupName {  
        get { 
            if (_uniqueGroupName == null) {  
                // For radio buttons, we must make the groupname unique, but can't just use the  
                // UniqueID because all buttons in a group must have the same name.  So 
                // we replace the last part of the UniqueID with the group Name.  
                string name = GroupName; 
                string uid = UniqueID; 

                if (uid != null) {  
                    int lastColon = uid.LastIndexOf(IdSeparator); 
                    if (lastColon >= 0) {  
                        if (name.Length > 0) {  
                            name = uid.Substring(0, lastColon+1) + name; 
                        }  
                        else if (NamingContainer is RadioButtonList) { 
                            // If GroupName is not set we simply use the naming 
                            // container as the group name 
                            name = uid.Substring(0, lastColon);  
                        } 
                    }  

                    if (name.Length == 0) { 
                        name = uid;  
                    } 
                } 

                _uniqueGroupName = name;  
            } 
            return _uniqueGroupName;  
        }  
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You want the UniqueID attribute:

> - **UniqueID** — The hierarchically-qualified unique identifier assigned to a control by the ASP.NET page framework.
> - **ClientID** — A unique identifier assigned to a control by the ASP.NET
>   page framework and rendered as the HTML ID attribute on the client.The
>   ClientID is different from the UniqueID because the UniqueID can
>   contain the colon character (:), which is not valid in the HTML ID
>   attribute (and is not allowed in variable names in client-side
>   script).

([from here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa720435%28v=vs.71%29.aspx))